# Call function once on day change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have a really straightforward problem that I can't seem to figure out. I'm using AngularJS and Firebase as a backend.

Basically, I have a function that I want to run once, every day, at midnight in order to do a value reset (set some object properties to false, etc.). The function works fine when I run it manually and works exactly as intended.

However, I can't seem to get it to run automatically on day change.

The function I want to run at midnight, once each day is `Fed.newDay()`. It's injected through the `Fed` factory to my `Dte` factory - which keeps an updated object with the days of the week, month etc.

Currently, in my `Dte` factory I have the following object:

```
var date = new Date();    

var Dte = { 

             currentDate: function() {
                ref.update({date: date.getDate()});

                ref.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
                    console.log('Dte registered new Day');
                    Fed.newDay();
                });

                return date.getDate();
             },
}
```

The goal here is to run `Fed.newDay()` once each time the date changes. I have stored the date in Firebase as follows:
[harrison -> date -> date: 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYhxS.jpg)

My assumption was that each time the date was updated on the server, the function would run based on Firebase's `ref.on('child_changed')...` method. When I `.set` the value manually, the function runs as expected, but will not run overnight on the automatic day change.

I've also tried using `setInterval` and `setTimeout` to run the function once every 86400000 milliseconds (1 day). I don't think these run when the application isn't being run, though.

There has to be something I'm overlooking here. Thanks for your time and help.

**Update:**

Just to clarify.

This is what I'm trying to do:

I have a two checkboxes that mark completion of a task that needs to be done by a group of people, the users. These two tasks only need to be done once, by any and only one user, once per day. After that day is over, I want to clear their values (set them to false) so that the same person OR a different person can check either of the two boxes.

I don't have a server running, I'm only using Firebase. Firebase has a value that I do have access to, that is currently updating the day of the month as long as someone uses the application that day.

**Solution:**

Thanks to @bmceldowney for the help.

This is the solution I arrived at. Also, please see the correct answer below in order to avoid problems that may arise if multiple users log in at 11:59.

```
    var Dte = {

        currentDate: function() {
            dateRef.update({date: date.getDate()});
            return date.getDate();
        },

        setLastUpdated: function(day) {
            dateRef.set({lastUpdated: day});
        },

        compareReset: function(last) {
            var current = Dte.currentDate();
            if (last !== current) {
                Fed.newDay();
                Dte.setLastUpdated(current);
            } else {
                console.log('no reset needed');
            }
        },

        load: function() {
            dateRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.val() != null) {
                    var data = snapshot.val();
                    var updateValue = data['lastUpdated'];
                    Dte.compareReset(updateValue);
                } else {
                    Dte.load();
                }
            })
        },
```

Comment: Do you want midnight local user time, or midnight GMT?

Comment: Midnight local user time, GMT-6, CST.

Comment: You say `setInterval` isn't an option because they won't run when the application isn't being run. That's going to be a problem for any solution running on the client.

Comment: Is there not a way for the application to load, detect a changed value on Firebase, and run a function.

Comment: I guess what you want is to run a CRON job. Simply create a cron job on your server having the code to change the object property, and set its time to 1 day.

Comment: @Himmel I don't think so. That would require firebase to keep track of when each of it's clients received the last value. I would suggest maybe caching the value on the client. That way on startup you can compare the current value vs. the cached value and do whatever you need.

Comment: This needs clarification... *"I don't think these run when the application isn't being run, though."* The simple fact that you need it to run even when the client isn't viewing the page makes it impossible to do this with client-side code. you'll have to do it server-side, or on page load.

Comment: @KevinB I was hoping to do it on page load somehow.

Comment: Where is the date being stored? you'll have to compare the current date to the last processed date, and if it's a new day, do x. you'll probably also want to have an interval running every 60 seconds or so (depending on how accurate you want it to be) that will detect rolling over to a new day, which will again do x.

Comment: @KevinB The new date is being stored in a Firebase object posted above. Each time the page loads, Javascript's `Date` object is instantiated, and if it's a new value from the one being stored on Firebase, it updates.

So basically I need to cache the last processed date onto the client, and then have the application compare the values of the current Date to the one cached on the client? 

It seems that the 60 second check would require I set up a server, and I'm using firebase to store information.

Comment: I don't know what firebase is, so i can't help you with that.

Comment: Caching and comparing values on load is a much easier solution then setting up a server.

Comment: The problem is that cacheing the values to the client would unload a particular value, let's say 23, for Sept. 23rd. If the client logs in and the value is 24, for Sept. 24, it would run the function fine. However, if another client logged in with 23, it would also run the function. And I only want the function to run once daily for all users...

Comment: Check my update above for clarification. There has to be an elegant solution for this. I can't conceptually understand how I could store a date every time a user logs in, and keep that date updated, and not call a function that resets values, only once, every time this date updates...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store a `lastUpdated` field in firebase. On client load, grab the value of `lastUpdated` and compare it to the current date. If it's different, run your `Fed.newDay` method and update the `lastUpdated` date.

EDIT:

As the TheSharpieOne points out in the comments, you'll want some sort of timer function running to make sure you get the appropriate behavior if a client is already logged in at the stroke of midnight. This leaves you open to a potential race condition that could result in `Fed.newDay` being called multiple times if multiple users are logged in at that time. These kinds of issues are almost impossible to fix without having a proper server that manages state appropriately.

Comment: This sounds like the right solution. Thank you. I'm going to try and implement it and I'll follow-up.